# Italian Currency in rendered PDF?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm doing a report by a visualforce page(`renderas="pdf"`).

I'd like to put Italian data format for the currency.

I've this code:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(line.myValue__c==0, 'OMAGGIO', '€ ' + TEXT(line.myValue__c))}"></apex:outputText>
```

The target is to have a dot for the thousands and the commas for the decimals.

How can i obtain this format?

Answer (score 0):

i've resolved!

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" rendered="{!line.myValue==0}" value="<b>OMAGGIO</b>" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!line.myValue}"/>
```

Comment: What exactly did you change? Can you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/223716/edit) this answer to include steps of your changes & more information, not just for yourself, but also for future readers?